# Inequality $ \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}<\sqrt{4n+2}. $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $n\in Z$ and $n>0$. Prove that there is no $x,y\in Z$ such that $x,y>0$ and
$$
\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}<\sqrt{4n+2}.
$$
Thank you for all kind help.

Comment: This question deserves a downvote because there no context.  Where did this problem come from, e.g.?  What have you tried?  Etc.   On the other hand, it deserves an upvote because it's an interesting problem.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that there exist two integer number $x,y>0$ such that 
$$
 \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}<\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}<\sqrt{4n+2} \qquad\qquad (1)
$$
From the left hand side of (1) and the Cauchy_Schwarz we have
    $$
 x+y\geq\frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{2}>\frac{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2}{2}>\frac{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n})^2}{2}=2n.
 $$
    Since $x+y>0$ is an integer number, we have $x+y\geq 2n+1$. 
    Taking square both sides of (1) we get
$$
 2n+1+2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-(x+y)<2\sqrt{xy}<4n+2-(x+y)\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
    Since $x+y\geq 2n+1$ we have $x+y=2n+1+k$ for some $k\geq 0$. Substituting $x+y$ into (2) we obtain
$$
2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k<2\sqrt{xy}<2n+1-k\qquad\qquad (3)
  $$
    From the above inequality we have $k<2n+1$. Therefore
    $$
k\leq 2n<2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}.
$$
    From here it implies that the left hand side of (3) is positive. Taking square both sides of (3) we get
    $$
(2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k)^2<4xy<(2n+1-k)^2.
$$
   On the other hand
$$
 (2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k)^2-((2n+1-k)^2-1)=(4n(n+1)+k^2-4k\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1})-(4n^2+4n+1+k^2-2k(2n+1)-1)
$$
$$
\quad =2k(2n+1-2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1})
$$
$$
\quad=2k(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})^2\geq 0.
$$
Hence
 $$
 (2n+1-k)^2-1\leq (2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-k)^2<4xy<(2n+1-k)^2.
 $$
This is absurd.